# Neo4j browser is shutdown

Tags: neo4j, garbage-collection, cypher, graph-databases

I am currently using `neo4j 2.2.5`. I have around 30 million real flights and around thousands airport. I have `Flight` and `Airport` nodes and also I have `HAS_FLIGHT` and `FLYING_TO` relationships. Those relationships are connected the two nodes, source `Airport` node has connected with `Flight` node by `HAS_FLIGHT` relationship and `Flight` nodes has connected by `FLYING_TO` relationship with destination `Airport`.

So my question is when I tried to find the path flight from London city to Tokyo city with maximum 2 layovers airports or transit airports, my query will take more than 20 minutes and finally the connection is lost.

Here is my query:

//Flights path from London to Tokyo

`MATCH path = (london :Airport{city:'London'})-[:HAS_FLIGHT|FLYING_TO*0..6]->(tokyo :Airport{city:'Tokyo'})
RETURN path;`

Comment: Do you have an index on `:Airport(city)`? In general, see [this blog post](http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-2-query-tuning/) for information on optimizing Cypher queries.

Comment: [tag:William] Yes I already created index.

Answer (score 1):

The query above gives you all the paths up to a level of 6. In most cases you just want the shortest path(s):

```
MATCH path = allShortestPaths( (london :Airport{city:'London'})-[:HAS_FLIGHT|FLYING_TO*0..6]->(tokyo :Airport{city:'Tokyo'}))
RETURN path;
```

`shortestPath` and `allShortestPaths` are way much faster since they skip paths that will get longer as early as possible. This should put much less pressure on memory and garbage collection.

Also double check on indexes as William mentioned in his comment.

Comment: [tag:StefanArmbruster] when I tried to execute that cypher I got `Java heap space` and I have already created constraints based on their flight_id and airport_id.